# Installing Data-Migration Tool in M2.3.3 without Composer

Tags: magento2, data-migration

Is it Possible to install Data Migration Tool Without using Composer ?
After Copying the files in vendor/magento/data-migration-tool, when i run migrate command this error occurs ..

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]There are no commands defined in the "migrate" namespace.
```

TIA.

Comment: i think issue of permission

Answer (score 0):

if you installed it as module, with `setup:upgrade` , after you clean your cache you will see this in modules list.